# Update Magento database to reflect default billing address

Tags: mysql, magento

I've just transferred 130,000 customers into Magento, so I'm hoping there is a MySQL query that can do the final step to save me from re-importing.

I'd like to run a query on the database to set the imported address from the transfer as being the "default billing address". When it's set as default, customer data is displayed and searchable in the Magento backend under `Customers -> Manage Customers`.

When manually setting the customers address to default in the backend, I know at least the following tables are updated (`customer_address_entity_int` and `customer_entity_int`). Not sure if this is the best approach, so any advice is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First You need to grab the attribute ID of `default_billing` from `eav_attribute`
- Then get the imported address ID you want to be default from   this table `customer_address_entity`.
- Finally search the `attribute_id` and `entity_id` ( `customer_id` ) and update the value column with `address_id`